# jQuery UI .scale() effect producing odd positioning jumps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scale

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7hu78bmd/3/)

**Description of problem:**

I'm attempting to make this image `scale` into view (centered), and then give the appearance that it's "bouncing" away from the screen briefly after reaching its maximum size of 100%. Unfortunately, it is moving down and to the right with each new effect chain. Why?

Note that the effect I'm attempting to achieve is completely different from the `bounce` effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'scale': 'box'` option for `scale` effect.

> scale (default: "both")
>
> Type: String
>
> Which areas of the element will be resized: "both", "box", "content". Box resizes the border and padding of the element; content resizes any content inside of the element.

As yours `box` div doesn't actually have any `content`, probably, that's the reason of unwanted shifts...

Yours [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpsx3L7x/) with modification.

Another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8edw53p/1/) variant.

**Upd.**

As you can see in second fiddle, you can use separate function for each animation phase (effect). So, just in outermost phase pick current box size, and in each next phase calc scale percentage with honored current/initial box size, like following:

```
var box = $('.box');
box.data('size', {'w': box.width(), 'h': box.height()});
box.show(scale_effect(box, 100, 250, function () {
    box.stop().effect(scale_effect(box, 80, 100, function () {
        box.stop().effect(scale_effect(box, 100, 100, function () {
            box.stop().effect(scale_effect(box, 90, 100, function () {
                box.stop().effect(scale_effect(box, 100, 100, function () {
                }));
            }));
        }));
    }));
}));

function scale_effect(box, percent, duration, complete) {
    box = $(box);
    var size = box.data('size');
    var absolutePercent = percent * size.w / box.width();
    console.log(absolutePercent);
    return {
        'effect': "scale", 
        'percent': absolutePercent,
        'scale': 'box',
        'duration': duration, 
        'queue': false,
        'complete': complete
    };
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8edw53p/3/) for preview.

And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/z8edw53p/4/) some nifty variant with following syntax:

```
$('.box').bouncedScale([
    {'percent': 100, 'duration': 250},
    {'percent': 80, 'duration': 100},
    {'percent': 100, 'duration': 100},
    {'percent': 90, 'duration': 100},
    {'percent': 100, 'duration': 100},
]);
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, and I appreciate your submission, but it unfortunately causes the element to shrink with each iteration if the image has an odd number of pixels (rounding problem). You can see this in practice by using one such image and then scaling it repeatedly.  Is there any way to reset the pixels of the element precisely without using a percentage-based approach?

Comment: @ahnkhzet, thanks for the update. You're doing some really great work, so I'm giving you the answer you got me close enough that I've modified your solution into something I can work with it. But all of these functions suffer from the same rounding errors which don't preserve height/width properly after a few iterations.  I think the best solution is to probably just use math that does not result in rounding errors for the browser to muck up, which is what I ended up doing.